# how to create a development url something like dev.abc.com for development porposes if i have domain abc.com

Tags: wordpress, url, dns

I have a domain for example **abc.com**

How can I create development environment **dev.abc.com** not **abc.com/dev**

Thanks for your time!

Comment: who is your server provider.???

Comment: @DevDanidhariya Godaddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the actual hosting is with GoDaddy, create a subdomain in their control panel: https://ca.godaddy.com/help/how-do-i-create-a-subdomain-in-simple-control-panel-2290

If your hosting is with someone else but your DNS is hosted with godaddy, create an A Record for the subdomain in GoDaddy: https://ca.godaddy.com/help/add-an-a-record-19238 with the value pointing to your server ip.

On the server-side, lets assume you're using cPanel, please follow this guide to add a subdomain: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/cpanel/cpanel-manage-domains/creating-a-subdomain

After creating the subdomain there should be a folder called subdomain (or whatever you named the subdomain) in your root folder or public_html , thats where you should be putting files for subdomain.abc.com.

Comment: Thanks man! it works for me